# why ECHO does not come up?

Tags: linux, sh

I have this shell :

```
===
#!/bin/sh -e

LogFile=/home/pi/logs/prova.log        # log file
test -e $LogFile || touch $LogFile     # create it if non existent

echo "(1) ======== ======== ======== Inici de PROVA.SH"     >>  $LogFile
echo "(2) ping 1.2.3.4"                                     >>  $LogFile
# ping  1.2.3.4  -W 3  -c 2                                   >>  $LogFile
echo "(3) start APP"                                        >>  $LogFile

echo "LOG file is" $LogFile
exit 0
===
```

The output is

1) one line to screen

2) three lines to file

But if the 8th line (ping 1.2.3.4) is un-commented,
the "echo's" after the 8th line do not get written,
neither to the screen, neither to the file.

I need to understand why, and how to solve it.

I guess is something related to the fact that "ping" runs in another shell,
so the "echo's" write there.

But I don't know how to fix it.

Any pointer or URL to documentation is welcome.
Sebastian.

Answer (score 0):

```
ping -W 3 -c  2 1.2.3.4 >>  $LogFile
```

Put the IP/Hostname after the ping options.

Comment: ping fails because 1.2.3.4 does not answer

Answer (score 0):

Most likely:

- `ping` fails because of wrong order of arguments: destination should be last.
- Your script runs with `-e` so it exits at first error, so it stops after `ping` fails.
- You don't redirect standard error for `ping` : the error message is lost
- If you remove `-e`, `ping` still fails, but the script continues, executes the last 2 lines and you get their output (but you do not get from ping because that goes to stderr)

Solution, 2 changes:

```
ping -W 3 -c 2 1.2.3.4    2>&1    >>  $LogFile
               ^^^^^^^    ^^^^
I.P as last argument  &   Redirect stderr to stdout before redirecting to file
```

Comment: putting the IP at the end makes no difference.

Comment: but removing "-e" makes it work, even there is no error. why is this ?

Comment: It does not "work", `ping` still fails, but without `-e` the script continues and you get the messages to the screen and the log... except that you only redirect `ping` 's stdout, you don't redirect stderr, so you don't *see* the error

Comment: when you say "ping fails" you mean there is no answer, as 1.2.3.4 is not a valid IP ?

Comment: No, we (both answers) mean you must put that as *last* argument to ping -- see my edited answer. If you worry about a simple&proper dummy IP address that works for examples, you can use 8.8.8.8, that will work for everyone.

Comment: IP is last in line now, no problem changing that. But if I use 8.8.8.8, then as Google answers the PING then there is no TIMEOUT. And I need the TIMEOUT setting, as it is the delay I need. And I need "-e" because I am in rc.local, jejeje

Comment: maybe I shall use SLEEP

Comment: Nobody said you should remove `-e` or the timeout. Only 2 things: change the order (see `man ping`), and add a redirection. Yes maybe you need some sleep, and reread all that later with a clear head :) [I don't know if you were joking yourself, but given the confusion, it's a good joke]

Comment: good joke, but out of place - here in Spain it is clear morning now. As I need the "-e" (because I am in rc.local) then I shall not use "ping" as it fails if the IP does not answer. I shall try to use "sleep 5". Thanks for the help and the optimistic view.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144642/discussion-between-hugues-moreau-and-sebastia-net).

Comment: Haha, after a quick chat, an interesting info: **ping on invalid IP with controlled timeout was there on purpose, in order to get the script to wait a few seconds**. In that case, yes, `sleep` is a much better idea (sorry for the borderline-inappropriate joke btw, but... was too funny to pass...)

Comment: This is why `-e` is generally not a good idea; it does not distinguish between "error I can live with" (`ping` failing) and "error that is unrecoverable".